# DB2- how to prevent user viewing view DDL

Tags: view, db2, ddl

i'm having this situation whereby user are using Dbeaver to access to DB2. There is some views created. At the moment user have the ability to use the Dbeaver to see the view DDL (back end code).

Question : how/is there any way to prevent the user see the view DDL?

much appreciate you advice

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Db2 [Obfuscation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=support-obfuscation) facility.

```
CALL DBMS_DDL.CREATE_WRAPPED ('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_OBFUSCATED AS SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA LIKE ''SYS%''');

SELECT TEXT
FROM SYSCAT.VIEWS
WHERE VIEWSCHEMA = CURRENT SCHEMA AND VIEWNAME = 'TEST_OBFUSCATED';
```

| TEXT |
| --- |
| CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_OBFUSCATED WRAPPED SQL11014 long_meaningless_string |

You may use this view as any other one in the same way, but its text is not visible for everyone.
Moreover, you can use this "strange" obfuscated statement to create the view from scratch. There is a scalar function which helps you to get this obfuscated statement without creation it first.

```
VALUES DBMS_DDL.WRAP ('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_OBFUSCATED AS SELECT TABNAME FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA LIKE ''SYS%''')
```

If someone still needs to view the real view text, you may use [Row and column access control (RCAC)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=security-row-column-access-control-rcac) on the `SYSIBM.SYSVIEWS` table.

Comment: thanks for your advice. will RCAC and obfuscation method cause the user not able to perform select query? my intention is to block/prevent the user to see the view definition/underlying code and at the same time user is allow to perform select query.

Comment: It would be strange enough, if the user couldn't use an obfuscated or RCAC masked view. It would be a useless feature in such a case. Sure, the user can use it as usual as I stated above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your users to be able to select from a view, they must be able to obtain the definition of that view.

You can wrap the query against the view in a set-returning user-defined function, which has all privileges of its creator, presumably a DBA, and grant other users only the `EXECUTE` privilege on that function. You will then be able to revoke from your users the privileges to read system catalog tables that you don't want them to read.

[Details in the manual](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=routines-authorizations-binding-that-contain-sql).